# How to overwrite a class just for a module in ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, syntax

Why doesn't this work?

```
module Magic
  class Fixnum
    def div2(other)
      self.to_f / other
    end

    alias :"/" :div2
  end
end

module SomeModule
  include Magic

  1/4 == 0.25 #should be true in here
end

1/4 == 0.25 #should be false everywhere else
```

Comment: A detail: `self.to_f` is OK, but `to_f` is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you posted yourself is actually changing `Fixnum` globally, which is not what you want. That is, with your solution:

```
module Magic
  class ::Fixnum
    def div2(other)
      self.to_f / other
    end

    alias :"/" :div2
  end
end

# Yields 0.25 instead of expected 0. 
# This line should not be affected by your Fixnum change, but is.
1/4
```

For the use case you describe, Ruby 2.0 introduced [refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which you can use like below. Please note that `using` a Module inside another Module is not possible in Ruby 2.0, but is in Ruby 2.1. So to use the `Magic` module inside `SomeModule` you will require Ruby 2.1. This might be a problem if you are using Windows since you will have to compile 2.1 yourself, the Windows binaries and installer are still at 2.0.

```
module Magic
  refine Fixnum do
    def /(other)
      self.to_f / other
    end
  end
end

1/4 # => 0
using Magic
1/4 # => 0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I need to access the `Fixnum` class at toplevel, the code should be:

```
module Magic
  class ::Fixnum
    def div2(other)
      self.to_f / other
    end

    alias :"/" :div2
  end
end
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your modifications to `Fixnum` to only apply certain places, you can use [refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html):

```
module Magic
  refine Fixnum do
    def foo
      "Hello"
    end
  end
end

class SomeClass
  using Magic

  10.foo # => "Hello"

  def initialize
    10.foo # => "Hello"
  end
end

10.foo # Raises NoMethodError
```

Your original example defines an *new* class called `Fixnum` within `Magic` (`Magic::Fixnum`). It does not touch the global `Fixnum`. The response you posted where you said `::Fixnum` modifies the global `Fixnum` class.